# Need to get column name and its type of a sql query

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I want to get columns and its data type from a *sql select statement* for a given sql connection .the code should capable to connect different RDBMS like (sql server,My sql,Oracle ,Etc..)

**Eg:**

```
1.select * from People
2.select Name As UserName,Id As Identity,Address from People
```

**Required Result:**

```
1.Name-string, Id-int, Address-string
2.UserName-string ,Identity-int, Address-string
```

Comment: Which sql? SQL Server, Oracle MS Access ?

Comment: There is no database-independent way of doing this.  You have to figure it out for each database.  I would suggest asking a separate question for each database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried both answers currently present, when had the same problem, but both didn't work under some conditions. For example, they can't diferentiate `DateTime` from `Date`, can't return size of some data types (`decimal(38,10)` for example), doesn't support some SQL native types such as `Money` etc. Finally I ended up with the following solution:

```
var schema = yourSqlCommand.ExecuteReader().GetSchemaTable();
var Columns = schema.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row=>new DbColumnInfo
    {
        Name = row.Field<string>("ColumnName"),
        SqlDataType = GetSqlTypeFromSchemaRow(row) //extract information about SQL type which I need, using schemaRow.Field<string>("DataTypeName"), schemaRow.Field<short>("NumericPrecision"), schemaRow.Field<short>("NumericScale") etc.
    }).ToArray();
```

`GetSchemaTable()` function returns SQL table which contains not the data you've selected, but metadata about it's columns (name, SQL type, nullability, identity parameters, primary key mark and many-many more). See full columns description [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable(v=vs.110).aspx).

I used it only with MS SQL Server, but methods `ExecuteReader()` and `GetSchemaTable()` are present in base classes, so I believe this should work with almost any SQL provider.

As for supported SQL statements - looks like it's any SQL which returns single dataset. I tried joins, computed columns, stored procedures and functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the select statement result in a DataTable in c#, I will try this:

```
        DataTable table = GetDataTable();
        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            var name = column.ColumnName;  // the column name
            var type = column.DataType.ToString();  // the type as string

        }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server:

Take a look at [this article about loading data into a DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399340(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can also look at the [FillSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/229sz0y5(v=vs.110).aspx) method on the DataSet in order to load schema information.

Once you have that you can iterate over the columns and their type.

```
dataSet.Table["SomeTable"].Columns
```

Comment: but i need to connect multiple RDBMS... I need to get this without using provider in connection string.